# Mouse Button Press in ROCCAT Macro Manager

Tags: mouse

I recently purchased a [ROCCAT Kone[+]](http://www.roccat.org/Products/Gaming-Mice/ROCCAT-Kone-/) which has some great macro possibilities due to [EasyShift](http://www.roccat.org/Products/Gaming-Mice/ROCCAT-Kone-/#crb_3), which allows you to bind extra commands to the other mouse buttons (accessed by holding the assigned EasyShift mouse button)

In the macro manager you can view all the in built macros and their key sequences. Below is an example which has mouse button presses:

[image: Macro Example - Shows in built macro with mouse button presses]

In trying to create my own I was not able to add mouse button presses to my macro using the recorder. How do I do this?

Comment: Dude, that's one awesome mouse. How much did that run you?

Comment: $130 AUD delivered. I absolutely love it!

Comment: Man, that's bloody brilliant!

Comment: 2500 views and one upvote. Sadface.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the sequence list (under 'KEY PRESS SEQUENCE') you need to right click and select 'Insert mouse event' after which you can select which button (or the mouse wheel) and what type of event (down/up/click)

Comment: Thanks. Also do you know if you can set macros up so that holding down the key doesn't keep triggering a key up then down event over and over? Rather that the key up doesn't occur until you let go?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think thats possible (or at least, I don't see any obvious way of doing that)

Comment: Ah well